# facebook extends permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a facebook android application. in this application there is the login (with relaative permission).in a second time i want to make a facebook share. The problem is that appear another permission(obviously)..i would like that was appears only one permission with both... how?? i addeed in the facebook console the publish_stream, but without result!!

Answer (score 0):

You cant define them both to the login button

If you want to publish you would need to "ask" from the current open session more Permission

Like:

```
private void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
    if (session != null && !session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
        System.out.println("SEESION Permission");
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(mainFragment, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        // demonstrate how to set an audience for the publish permissions,
        // if none are set, this defaults to FRIENDS
        //  .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}
```

For more information about permission visit:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton/#setReadPermissions(List)